# Foreign key constrait fail

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables:

```
create table comuni(
comune varchar(20) primary key,
cap char(5) not null,
abitanti int not null
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table mercati(
ubicazione varchar(20) not null,
comune varchar(20) not null,
primary key(ubicazione,comune),
foreign key(comune) references comuni(comune)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table posteggi(
identificativo char(3) not null,
mq int not null,
CHECK(mq>=3),
acquistato bool not null DEFAULT 1,
ubicazione varchar(20) not null,
comune varchar(20) not null,
codice_fiscale char(16),
primary key(identificativo,ubicazione,comune),
foreign key(ubicazione,comune) references mercati(ubicazione,comune),
foreign key(codice_fiscale) references commercianti(codice_fiscale)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

In the first table I've insert two rows

```
+-----------+-------+----------+
| comune    | cap   | abitanti |
+-----------+-------+----------+
|  tribano  | 35020 |     6000 |
| monselice | 35023 |     5020 |
+-----------+-------+----------+
```

then in the second one row,

```
+----------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+
| ubicazione     | giorno | ora_inizio | ora_fine | comune   |
+----------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+
| piazza mazzini | GI     | 07:00:00   | 13:00:00 |  tribano |
+----------------+--------+------------+----------+----------+
```

but when i try to execute

```
insert into posteggi(identificativo,mq,ubicazione,comune) 
values('10',10,'piazza mazzini','tribano');
```

which exist in table mercati I have this error:

> *ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (ntresold-ES.posteggi, CONSTRAINT posteggi_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (ubicazione, comune) REFERENCES mercati (ubicazione, comune))*

Yes, the problem was the space before "tribano", I remove it and works with the code in Pheonix's answer

Comment: It seems that you have leading spaces in the the value of `comune` for the existing row in `mercati` whereas the value `'tribano'` you insert into `posteggi` does not have a leading space. (But that might have been caused by the formatting on SO).

Comment: Another thing: the check constraint on `posteggi.mq` is useless. MySQL does not support check constraints (but it will not tell you).

Comment: Works for me if I make sure that there are no spaces: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67d60/1

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e2cc2/0)

**MySQL 5.5.30 Schema Setup**:

```
create table comuni(
comune varchar(20) primary key,
cap char(5) not null,
abitanti int not null
);


create table mercati(
ubicazione varchar(20) not null,
comune varchar(20) not null,
primary key(ubicazione,comune),
foreign key(comune) references comuni(comune)
);

create table posteggi(
identificativo char(3) not null,
mq int not null,
CHECK(mq>=3),
acquistato bool not null DEFAULT 1,
ubicazione varchar(20) not null,
comune varchar(20) not null,
codice_fiscale char(16),
primary key(identificativo,ubicazione,comune),
foreign key(ubicazione,comune) references mercati(ubicazione,comune)
);
```

Comment: Now it works, but in this way I could do this: insert into posteggi(identificativo,mq,ubicazione,comune) 
values('10',10,'aaaaa','tribano'); which do not respect the reference integrity, cause in table mercati doesn't exist a row whith comune=tribano and ubicazione=aaaaa

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : ohh. didn't know that. Saw the fiddle and corrected the problem. We can create composite foreign keys also that i was unaware of. Thanks for correction.

Comment: commercianti(codice_fiscale) could be null, but now I try whitout it

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : removed it .